# subclassing: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm attempting to subclass a built-in Qt ui class. In QtDesigner I "promote" a QGraphicsView to a "ResultView" and add an include in the class where the UI is loaded and using

```
uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
```

to load the ui sheet

Just so I can make sure its loading correctly the subclass only looks like this

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ResultView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResultView, self).__init__()
```

Which, unless I'm missing something will simply just create a qgraphicsview that has a different name.

However, I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

what second argument am I sending?

Demoting back to the qgraphicsview fixes the error, so I am pretty sure its within this class that is causing it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1023, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/swalsh/Desktop/Mandelbrot/main.py", line 89, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "C:/Users/swalsh/Desktop/Mandelbrot/main.py", line 15, in __init__
    uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 226, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 72, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix, basedir)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1000, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 807, in createUserInterface
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 482, in createLayout
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 525, in handleItem
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 482, in createLayout
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 525, in handleItem
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 482, in createLayout
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 525, in handleItem
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 482, in createLayout
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 525, in handleItem
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 253, in createWidget
    self.stack.push(self.setupObject(widget_class, parent, elem))
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 217, in setupObject
    obj = self.factory.createQObject(clsname, name, args, is_attribute)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py", line 124, in createQObject
    return self._cpolicy.instantiate(factory, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\swalsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\qobjectcreator.py", line 139, in instantiate
    return clsObject(*ctor_args)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Please post the complete Traceack when asking about code that throws an exception - format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ResultView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ResultView, self).__init__(parent)
```

or

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ResultView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResultView, self).__init__(self.parent)
```

the correct syntax is:

```
super(AnotherDialog, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```

Comment: https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-December/038428.html

Comment: thanks. Without the line number I was too focused on the super().__init__(). The first version worked while, for whatever reason, the second gave the same error.