# Loading promoted subclass from Qt Designer results in TypeError

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using Qt Designer and trying to promote a subclass `QLabel`. I created a ui.file and tried to load it with the individual Label. The code (`main.py` file) looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import os
import sys


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(basedir, "gui", "Test.ui"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyDragDropWindow()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 1000, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The corresponding code of `MyLabel` is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel).__init__()
```

When running the code, the following error occurs: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

The promoting window looks like this:
[image]
The `MyLabel` file is located in the `MyWidgets` folder, which is in the same folder as the `main.py` file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675279/subclassing-init-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given) solution does not work.

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All QWidget based classes always accept a keyword argument for their parent, which defaults to `None`.

The UI loader always creates widgets with their parent as argument.

While, for most situations, it's normally enough to just declare the `__init__` with a single "parent" positional argument, it's considered best practice to always use the `*args, **kwargs` signature for both the function definition *and* the super call (as long as the arguments respect the base class constructors).

```py
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In case you need custom arguments for dynamically created widgets, then you have different choices, considering that the first argument will *always* be the parent:

- define a specific signature, like `def __init__(self, parent, someArg, [...][, *args][, **kwargs]):` and then `super().__init__(parent)`;
- (better) use keyworder/named arguments, and, in that case:

  - if you declare named arguments, *always* use a default `parent=None` as first argument;
  - *pop* other possible keyworded arguments from `kwargs` before calling the base implementation;
  - use keyworded arguments for custom Qt properties through the `pyqtProperty` (`Property` for PySide) decorator or function, but also remember that they will always be set in the `super().__init__()` call, so if there's anything that's required to the processing of those arguments happens *after* that, you need to pop those values from `kwargs` and eventually set the property afterwards;

<sup>Note: since Python 3, `super()` doesn't normally need any argument, but if you specify them, they have to be correct: `super(MyLabel).__init__()` is ***wrong***, as the instance must be declared along with the class in order to properly resolve the initialization: you either do `super(MyLabel, self).__init__()` or you just use the default and normally suggested `super().__init__()`.</sup>